# Silverlight 8.1 application hangs on "loading..." after moving to SD card

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

What are the reasons that prevent WP Silverlight app 8.1 from working on SD? Application don't even enter App constructor or Application_Launched.

Comment: Can you share your app.xaml.cs code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving app from phone storage to SD card and vice versa is possible only if app was installed from storage package.